# docker compose inside docker in a docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am pretty new to docker and was following the documentation found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/), trying deploy several containers inside dind using docker-compose 1.14.0 I get the following

```
docker run -v /home/dudarev/compose/:/compose/ --privileged docker:dind /compose/docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/dockerd-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 21: /compose/docker-compose: not found
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: You need to install docker-compose command in your container. It doesn't come with compose by default

Comment: If you are new to docker, let me first ask you if you are certain you want a docker-in-docker setup? Check [this](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) blog post (specifically "the solution" part).

Comment: @JonesV yes, `dind` is a must, it is used to build and test images and keep the host docker clean,  nevertheless the one which is hosted on docker hub is based on busybox and for some reason it seems not to be able to find the binary, but if you build the image from original repo, as it has a proper bash (not ash like in busybox) it find it. I must be something to do with how busybox mounts the filesystem and I am quite confused here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add docker-compose installation to your Dockerfile before executing docker run.

For example, if you have an Ubuntu docker, add to your **Dockerfile**:

```
RUN aptitude -y install docker-compose
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /compose/docker-compose
```

Because it looks like if your entry-point looks up docker compose in /compose folder, while docker-compose is installed in /usr/local/bin by default.

> If you want a concrete docker-compose version (for example 1.20.0-rc2):

```
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.20.0-rc2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /compose/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /compose/docker-compose
```

Comment: Had to use the following to get the install working:

`RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`
`RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Answer (score 16):

There is [official](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose/) docker image on dockerhub for docker-compose, just use that.

Follow these steps:

- Create a directory on host `mkdir /root/test`
- Create `docker-compose.yaml` file with following contents:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  redis:
    image: redis
```

- Run `docker run` command to run docker-compose inside the container.

```
docker run -itd -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /root/test/:/var/tmp/ docker/compose:1.24.1  -f /var/tmp/docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

**NOTE:** Here /var/tmp directory inside the container will contain docker-compose.yaml file so I have used `-f` option to specify complete path of the yaml file. Also `docker.sock` is mounted from host onto the container.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

here is a full dockerfile to run docker-compose inside docker

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y pip
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```