# Instal docker client and docker compose inside a docker file (Node js application)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a node js application running on alpine with dockerfile already up and running.

I need to add docker-composer to run in from inside my container  and of course, mapped a volume of docker-sock and docker compose files into the container

my docker file is :

```
#---- Base Node ----

FROM node-build AS base

ADD package.json package-lock.json /app/
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/

# ---- Dependencies ----
FROM base AS dependencies
RUN npm install --production 
RUN cp -R node_modules prod_node_modules
RUN npm install

# ---- Build ----
FROM dependencies AS build
COPY . .
RUN npx tsc

# ---- Release ----
FROM base AS release
# copy production node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/prod_node_modules ./node_modules
# copy app sources
COPY --from=build /app/dist .

RUN rm -rf src
CMD pm2-runtime process.yml
```

I tried to use the following link and add there dockerfile into mine but I did not manage, i managed only add docker client without compose

https://github.com/wernight/docker-compose/blob/master/Dockerfile

and:

https://github.com/Cethy/alpine-docker-compose/blob/master/Dockerfile
https://github.com/Cethy/alpine-docker-client/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: You should make use of offcial docker-compose image from dockerhub Check this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/56785780/6790948

Comment: hi but how do i do that from docker file